# How to calculate tides for specific date and location with Delphi

Tags: delphi

Just saw this question in Stack [How to calculate sunrise and sunset time for current date with Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616245/how-to-calculate-sunrise-and-sunset-time-for-current-date-with-delphi)

Is there any way to calculate tides ? for a date and location.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

No. Sunrise and sunset is based on the simple fact that the earth is (almost) a sphere that is lit by the sun.

Tides are also based on the geographic properties on the land.

For instance the island of Great Brittain influences the tides along the Dutch and Belgian coasts because the water takes time to flow though the street of Calais.

That is why the local government publishes tides tables for most regions of the world.

See also http://www.ehow.com/how_7705476_calculate-ocean-tides.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any existing solutions in Delphi, but it's certainly possible.
WxTide32 is the most well known free tide program.
A good place to do some research would be 
http://www.wxtide32.com/links.html